# Need to remove the empty space to the left of the graph, after I moved the stocktools to the top of the graph in highstocks

Tags: highcharts

I have a small concern. I am using high stocks along with stock tools, But as per my requirement I have moved the stock tools to the top of the graph and now I am having an empty space to the left of my graph which should be removed. I am very naive to CSS and therefore I tried make marginLeft as 0 in chartOptions, but that did not work out. Any suggestion from high charts team will be very helpful. Please see the screen shot below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That problem is more related with internal spacing calculations, to prevent taking into account stock tools add this small plugin:

```
(function(H) {
    H.wrap(H.Chart.prototype, 'getMargins', function(proceed) {
        var storedStockTools = this.stockTools;
        // don't consider stock tools in get margins
        this.stockTools = null;

        proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        // restore stock tools
        this.stockTools = storedStockTools;
    });
}(Highcharts));
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/aer80c1b/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts

Comment: Awesome, this plugin works just fine for me. However I want to understand what exactly this plugin is doing and what is the argument 'H 'here. I am asking this because I am working on typescript and I might have to declare the type of arguments of the function.

Comment: Hi @Nishit, The `H` argument is just `Highcharts` and `this` points to chart.

Comment: Can i give any type to this 'H'?

Comment: I think that you can do the same thing as here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/master/ts/Core/Globals.ts#L207